# Apply Css In symfony 1.4 Autogenerate Class

Tags: css, symfony, symfony-1.4

I want Display Fields Which is below .. Fields are display properly .. but i want to Apply css for margin .. so how to do this ?

```
 $this->setWidgets(array(
  'id'            => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
  'submission_id' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'user_id'       => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
 // 'field_id'      => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('DataFields'), 'add_empty' => true)),
  'value'         => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'duration'      => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'units'         => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => array('In Days' => 'In Days', 'In Months' => 'In Months'))),
  //'avg_score'     => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply a css style as follow example:

```
$w = new sfWidgetFormInputText(
  array('default' => 'Fabien'),
  array('class' => 'foo')
);
```

You could also try to set a specific inline style with the following:

```
$w = new sfWidgetFormInputText();
$w->setOptions(array('default' => 'Fabien'));
$w->setAttributes(array('style' => '"color:blue;margin-left:30px;"'));
```

More info [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/A-Widgets) in the doc

Hope this help

Comment: i write inline css... So it's Working But In sfWidgetFormChoice margin-top can not worked ..

      ''         => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => array('In Days' => 'In Days', 'In Months' => 'In Months')),array("style"=>'width: 390px;margin-top:-90px')),

Comment: have you check the generated html? See nothing?

Comment: Nop .. Not have HTML

Comment: very strange, try with the second method i post in the answer and try cleaning the cache....